# Renaming CodeIgniter project folder causes "The requested URL not found" error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created my project with CodeIgniter and I put it on MAMP and it works correctly. The folder name was "Project" but I've changed it now into "Filmsite".

I've changed the `base_url` in config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/Project/';
```

to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/Filmsite/';
```

If I open the index the site works well, but if I try to click on a link a receive this message:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /Project/index.php was not found on this
>   server.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the project is not located in the root of domain, my best guess is you probably have `RewriteBase /Project/` within your `.htaccess` file **or** a rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If so, simply change `Project` to whatever you want.

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file, have I to create it?

Comment: @Italiano No you don't have to. However based on the incoming error, maybe the hyperlinks are hard-coded. Could you please provide some details including the URL in address bar which you've entered?

Comment: The URL in the page is:
http://example.com/Filmsite/manage
But I receive the error Not Found The Url /Project/index.php was not found on this server, it's strange.
But if I call the folder "Project" everything works perfectly

Comment: @Italiano According to the URL there should be a `.htaccess` file  (which is hidden by default) inside `Filmsite` folder. Because of the absence of `index.php` in URL. Make sure that hidden files are shown.

Comment: How can I see the hidden files?

Comment: Thank you, the problem was on the .htaccess file and now I solved it :)